# Consequences of blocking Graph API Explorer on Facebook?

Tags: facebook

Recently, I've seen a surge in some of my Facebook friends robotically liking posts that are clearly spam. I block the pages, but the same spammy posts always show up again on new pages that I haven't blocked. Whenever I open a post's dropdown menu to block the page in question, I'm also always given the option to block Graph API Explorer. What is Graph API Explorer, and does anything good ever come from it such that I'd regret blocking it?

Answer (score 1):

From [Facebook for developers](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/overview):

> The Graph API is the primary way to get data in and out of Facebook's platform. It's a low-level HTTP-based API that you can use to query data, post new stories, manage ads, upload photos and a variety of other tasks that an app might need to do.

If you think its spam then block it, nothing wrong to blocking it and report to Facebook about this.

Report spam you see in your feed to Facebook. Learn how to report spam in [Facebook Help Center](https://www.facebook.com/help/205730929485170).